# include or link external library libcurl to program

Tags: c, curl

I have downloaded the curl-8.6.0, and extract it to a folder. I have a program and need to link it with the library

My curl library folder

```
C:.
└───curl-8.6.0
    ├───CMake
    │   └───Platforms
    ├───docs
    │   ├───cmdline-opts
    │   ├───examples
    │   └───libcurl
    │       └───opts
    ├───include
    │   └───curl
    ├───lib
    │   ├───vauth
    │   ├───vquic
    │   ├───vssh
    │   └───vtls
    ├───m4
    ├───packages
    │   ├───OS400
    │   │   └───rpg-examples
    │   └───vms
    ├───plan9
    │   ├───include
    │   ├───lib
    │   └───src
    ├───projects
    │   └───Windows
    │       ├───VC14
    │       │   ├───lib
    │       │   └───src
    │       ├───VC14.10
    │       │   ├───lib
    │       │   └───src
    │       ├───VC14.20
    │       │   ├───lib
    │       │   └───src
    │       └───VC14.30
    │           ├───lib
    │           └───src
    ├───scripts
    ├───src
    ├───tests
    │   ├───certs
    │   │   └───scripts
    │   ├───data
    │   ├───http
    │   │   └───clients
    │   ├───libtest
    │   ├───server
    │   └───unit
    └───winbuild
```

my main.c

```
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  CURLcode ret;
  CURL *hnd;

  hnd = curl_easy_init();
  curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 102400L);
  curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com/");
  curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L);
  curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "curl/8.5.0");
  curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 50L);
  curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, (long)CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2TLS);
  curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_FTP_SKIP_PASV_IP, 1L);
  curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE, 1L);

  /* Here is a list of options the curl code used that cannot get generated
     as source easily. You may choose to either not use them or implement
     them yourself.

  CURLOPT_WRITEDATA was set to an object pointer
  CURLOPT_INTERLEAVEDATA was set to an object pointer
  CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION was set to a function pointer
  CURLOPT_READDATA was set to an object pointer
  CURLOPT_READFUNCTION was set to a function pointer
  CURLOPT_SEEKDATA was set to an object pointer
  CURLOPT_SEEKFUNCTION was set to a function pointer
  CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER was set to an object pointer
  CURLOPT_STDERR was set to an object pointer
  CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION was set to a function pointer
  CURLOPT_HEADERDATA was set to an object pointer

  */

  ret = curl_easy_perform(hnd);

  curl_easy_cleanup(hnd);
  hnd = NULL;

  return (int)ret;
}
```

my command to link it on command promt

```
C:\curltest>gcc -Wall -std=c99 -o my_program -IC:\curllll\curl-8.6.0\include -LC:\curllll\curl-8.6.0\lib main.c -lcurl
C:/Mingw64posix/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcurl
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why my gcc can not find my library.

Comment: You downloaded the source code of curl. You need to compile curl too. Better yet, use a package manager such as vcpkg or conan so you don't have to build curl yourself.

Comment: Can you tell me a bit about that ?

Comment: The file you downloaded contains a README file that links to [the install instructions](https://curl.se/docs/install.html)

Comment: Download and install the relevant binary from https://curl.se/download.html